# Drawing an excellent cow

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working in a big farm as a statistician and my master asked me to draw something to remind him his childhood. It was not easy for me to do that, because there was one big restriction: to do everything using only R. That's how I did that. Could you be so kind and help me to draw better cow?

```
library(ggplot2)

sim=function(xy){
  xx=xy[,"x"]*(-1)
  yy=xy[,"y"]
  gg=xy[,"gr"]
  xy=rbind(xy,cbind(xx,yy,gg))
  return(as.data.frame(xy))
}

circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
  r = diameter / 2
  tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
  xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
  yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
  return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}

n=100 

akys <- circleFun(c(1,5),1.5,npoints = n)
akys=as.matrix(cbind(akys,gr=4))
akys=sim(akys)

akys21 <- circleFun(c(1,4.5),0.5,npoints = n)
akys21=as.matrix(cbind(akys21,gr=5))

akys22 <- circleFun(c(-1,5.3),0.7,npoints = n)
akys22=as.matrix(cbind(akys22,gr=5))

nosis=circleFun(c(0.6,1),0.6,npoints = n)
nosis=as.matrix(cbind(nosis,gr=6))
nosis=sim(nosis)

x=c(0,1,3,3,2,0,0,1,1,0,3,5,2)
y=c(0,0,4,6,7,7,0,0,2,2,6,10,7)
gr=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1)
xy=cbind(x=x,y=y,gr=gr)

data=sim(xy)
data=rbind(data,akys,akys21,akys22,nosis)

ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=data,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,fill=factor(gr),group=gr), linetype=0, colour="black")+theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("cornsilk2","chocolate4","lightpink","white","black","maroon4"))+
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),legend.position="none",panel.grid=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank())+xlab("")+ylab("")+
  ggtitle("Crazy Cow Wishing You Happy Easter!!!")
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this would be better as a self-answered question...

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'm pondering its worth at all.

Comment: You may have to butter us up a bit more to get this done. You shouldn't really be milking StackOverflow like this. Mooove on to something else, no bull next time.

Comment: I'll ask the mods to move this to livestockoverflow.com

Comment: The `sim` function must be defined before calling it for `akys` and `nosis`.

Comment: I'm running R 2.14 and getting an `initRefFields` error, which seems to be a known problem in 2.14 (and I don't feel like upgrading right now). Can someone post an image of the output? I want to see the cow!

Comment: @DavidMarx: There's also a link to it at the bottom of the question, the See Here.

Comment: This question is currently being discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174159/158605)

Comment: The question has been reopened. OP, do you care to move your code to an Answer and rephrase the question more generally along the lines of drawing using graphics primitives? Otherwise this will no doubt soon disappear from [so] once the close/delete votes flood in...

Comment: @SynergyParnu When you say *"Help me to draw better cow?"*, do you mean a better-looking cow? A more complete cow instead of just the head? Or does "better" refer to something else, like code quality or performance?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the *fields* package?

Comment: @Spacedman: I think *two* highly-upvoted joke comments is enough. If you have absolutely nothing constructive to add to the question, please refrain.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are on Linux and have `cowsay` installed the solution is fairly straightforward:

```
> system("cowsay I quit")
 ________
< I quit >
 --------
    \   ^__^
     \  (oo)\_______
        (__)\       )\/\
            ||----w |
            ||     ||
```

Comment: As I remember, cow can be male.

Comment: I believe a male cow is a bull.  and I also believe this is awesome

Comment: Plus I grew up on a farm, I see an udder, 4 legs and a tail, nothing else that indicates maleness.  I believe we're in a grey area now.

Comment: He wants a cow of the `R` breed, not `Perl` -_-

Comment: Who said you can't use R to output ascii art? :)

Comment: @Rachel, the [ggplot2] tag

Comment: @GSee the OP says can you improve on this. The tag in and of itself doesn't mean the solution *must* be in that package. It just categorises the question.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, Rachel, I would suppose it's the same language at least. Or are we accepting answers to every R-problem with a `system(.)` command now?

Comment: @Arun Why not - R and S have always embraced extension via other languages and libraries!

Comment: @GavinSimpson The point isn't that it "isn't an answer", it's that it's an obviously bad (but fun!) answer that nonetheless attracted 18 up votes almost instantly.

Comment: @joran it *is* an answer - it isn't a good one if the question is draw a better cow in **ggplot2**.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, I beg to differ. The packages may be implemented in other languages. But I'd still like to *write my code* in R from that package, especially when the tag is R.

Comment: @Arun sorry but I beg to differ with your differing. S was designed to easily pull in existing fortran code for example. If the solution was to arrange for a call to some fancy wizz-bang javascript dataviz code to do the drawing, no-one would be complaining and this would have far more than 18 up votes. And Drew **does** use R code...

Comment: I guess I have misunderstood what `r` tag means then. I dint know people could fire up `system(.)` answers because it is a command within R. I'll try and remember that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson The wizz-bang javascript dataviz code you describe sounds like more of an improvement over the OP's ggplot than, say, some plain text in a terminal.

Comment: @GSee, "improvement" is subjective :). Let the up-votes keep coming!

Comment: @Arun, but I don't think there's anything wrong with using `system()` in an answer to a question in the [r] tag..

Comment: @GSee, yes. I understand that. Apparently it is okay even under `ggplot2` tag.